# Android HTTP post not working

Tags: android

It's my first time making http post or get. Am trying my best to get it working here is my code and url: http://ownvehicle.askmid.com/

Not sure why I am not getting response also there is a captcha image there not sure how to get that to imageview and send the data.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity2Activity extends Activity{

    TextView content;
    EditText fname, email, login, pass;
    String Name, Email, Login, Pass;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        content    =   (TextView)findViewById( R.id.content );
        fname      =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
       // email      =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
       // login      =    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginname);
       // pass       =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


        Button saveme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

        saveme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try{

                    // CALL GetText method to make post method call
                    GetText();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    content.setText(" url exeption! " );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Create GetText Metod
    public  void  GetText()  throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        // Get user defined values
        Name = fname.getText().toString();
       // Email   = email.getText().toString();
       // Login   = login.getText().toString();
        //Pass   = pass.getText().toString();

        // Create data variable for sent values to server

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("regno", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8");

      //  data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "="
           //     + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8");

    //    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")
           //     + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");

       // data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8")
               // + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        // Send data
        try
        {

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL("http://ownvehicle.askmid.com/");

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        // Show response on activity
        content.setText( text  );

    }

}
```

here is layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Something Below:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=""
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=""
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=""
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=""
        android:layout_below="@+id/save"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you added permission for accessing internet in your manifest??

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Does it showing any error in logcat or you are getting an empty response??

Comment: nuffin just idel also i checked the site maybe in the code the submit button isnt clicking the button on site ? also i seen there is a checkbox in site also

Answer (score 2):

You are using `try / catch` blocks where `catch` intercepts the exceptions but doesn't write anything to logcat which is why you aren't seeing any error messages.

*NEVER* use empty `catch` blocks - it defeats the object of exception handling and its use in debugging. At the very least print the stack trace. Example...

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace()`
}
```

The problem is you are trying to execute network code on the main / UI thread which means it will be throwing a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

If you want to execute network code you'll need to use a separate thread such as that provided by [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: exactly I was about to answer this question , plus he may make post request  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");